# How long do empty ships stay in space?

Tags: eve-online

If you were to leave a ship inside a POS bubble, how long would that ship stay in space? Is it like a container that pops after 2 hours, or is it closer to an anchored secure container that stays for 30 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside a POS bubble, a ship will stay in place indefinitely. Outside of a POS bubble, rookie ships and shuttles will stay for 30 days, and other ship types will stay indefinitely. Of course, by indefinitely I mean until someone finds it.

Comment: Abandoned ships outside of a POS bubble can make for easy, stat padding kills.  Baring that, I have personally stolen a ship that was bumped out of a bubble during a POS siege.  The owners were none to happy to see that.